# Programmatically enter password on prompt within Python?

Tags: python, macos, expect

I need functionality similar to the Unix `expect` from within a Python script, as an external executable is prompting for password. I am currently doing this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("execA",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

where `execA` is prompting for password. I'd like to wrap it with "expect" to supply said password.

There seem to be a few alternatives:

[Pexpect - Noah Spurrier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/)

[Python Expect](http://code.google.com/p/python-expect/)

What is the best way to do this? If there's a more efficient way to go about it, I'd love to know.

Comment: Try not to ask for "preferences" (asking for opinions is against the FAQ) but experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pexpect is the one I've used in the past to do things like this.

Though depending on the program it might be sufficient to just write to it's stdin?

Comment: Thanks for your help, pexpect is what I used, but I also learnt that for kerberos integrated passwords a keytab file maybe a better option. Writing to stdin does not work if the password prompt is displayed after some processing. hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of programs typically access the tty directly and put it in "raw" mode. So the stdio pipes don't work. You need to spawn the subprocess in a pty. A simple read/write with that might work. Those "expect-like" modules are usually for more complex scenarios.

Of course I prefer [this one](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/process/pycopia/expect.py), but I'm not sure it will work on OSX.